# Suppressing section '.ARM.exidx' with clang / llvm

Tags: arm, clang, llvm, cortex-m, bare-metal

I am trying to compile a bare-metal ARM Cortex-M3 program with `clang`. (Code and linker script work fine with gcc.)

My issue is that `clang` seems to emit a section `.ARM.exidx` whether it is needed or not.

Since for my code, gcc did not emit a `.ARM.exidx` section, my linker script thus does not specify a region for it. clang however seems to emit it as indicated by this error message:

```
ld.lld: error: no memory region specified for section '.ARM.exidx'
clang: error: ld.lld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to avoid generating this section when it is not needed?

I tried the options `-fno-unwind-tables` and `-fno-exceptions` but it seems to be a known bug that they do not work as expected. See these pull requests: [D31139](https://reviews.llvm.org/D31139) and [D31140](https://reviews.llvm.org/D31140)

---

I am currently working around this issue with the following section defition in the linker script:

```
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx)
    }
```

That seems a bit fragile though since the section will be missing if due to any changes to the code, the section is required at a later point.

Comment: Yeah thats how I am doing it as well, same issues same conclusion.  I my case I have no reason to unwind the stack so just want to be rid of the error...

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for letting me know. Do you know how by any chance how stable the content of `.ARM.exidx` is when it is not required? I.e. could one do a binary check/hash check of the emitted section and disregard it if it is the usual "null"-section and print an error/warning if its contents have changed because it actually becomes necessary after a code change? Or does it change with the rest of the code even when unused?

Comment: honestly dont know the answer to that.  AFAIK I dont see gnu building that section in the things I create or work on.  I have only just seen it recently with playing with clang/llvm and have not figured out how to turn it off.  its a side project so not moving very fast to have these kinds of answers yet...I have not dug into what the contents actually are when created (by clang/llvm)

Comment: @old_timer Same for me. Thought I would ask... Many thanks.